# Spring annotation @Profile disallowed for this location

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a configuration file where I want to create different beans depending on a profile.

For some reason, this is working :

```
@Configuration
@Profile("myProfile")
public class myClass {
```

and this is not, giving the error message in Eclipse:

> The annotation `@Profile` is disallowed for this location

```
@Bean
@Profile("myProfile")
```

I would rather use the second one, but I'm not sure if I can. Spring API says it should work :

> The `@Profile` annotation may be used in any of the following ways:
>
> - as a type-level annotation on any class directly or indirectly
>     annotated with `@Component`, including `@Configuration` classes
> - as a
>     meta-annotation, for the purpose of composing custom stereotype
>     annotations
> - as a method-level annotation on any @Bean method

I'm using Sping Framework 3.1.0, is it possible that the use on `@Bean` method was introduced only after?

Comment: what code are you trying to run? any exceptions you can share? what exactly does not work?

Comment: I'm trying to run JUnit tests using this bean configuration. When I run tests, I get this message : 
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The annotation @Profile is disallowed for this location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it was introduced in Spring 4.

- [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) in version 3.2.9.RELEASE only allows this annotation to be placed on a type.

  > @Target(value=TYPE)
- [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) in version 4.0.0.RELEASE allows this annotation to be placed on a type and on a method.

  > @Target(value={TYPE,METHOD})

Answer (score 3):

In [Spring 3.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v3.2.15.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.java#L76) profile annotation was restricted to a type. Since [Spring 4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.java#L78) you can use `@Profile` on a method too.

You'll need to update your Spring version to at least version 4.

Comment: Can't really do that, I prefer to create differents classes for each profile I want

Comment: Yes. That is a valid alternative.